# Separate paragraphs using linux

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file that contains connected paragraphs. I need to separate each paragraph with a blank line. Each paragraphs should begin with an `>FP0` pattern, however because the paragraphs are connected to each other, this pattern is not found at the beginning of the line in the current file. I have tried a `sed` command but it separated them according the line that contains `>FP0` pattern but it did not make it at the beginning of the new paragraphs.

Example of the paragraphs

```
>FP004340TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT>FP00598AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA>FP005521GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

The sed code used was

```
sed '/>/s/^/\n/'
```

and the output was

```
>FP004340TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

TTT>FP00598AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

A>FP005521GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

(I need no characters before >FP0 at the beginning of the new paragraphs.)

Comment: I had to guess a bit as to what the proper formatting should look like here; please review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use perl instead:

```
$ perl -pe 's/>/\n\n>/g' file


>FP004340TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

>FP00598AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

>FP005521GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

But that adds an extra blank line if the first character of the file is a `>`. So you can limit it to only replace `>` if they are preceded by another character:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.)>/$1\n\n>/g' file
>FP004340TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

>FP00598AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

>FP005521GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

Or, with GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.)>/\1\n\n>/g' file
>FP004340TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

>FP00598AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

>FP005521GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

And with any `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.\)>/\1\
\
>/g' file
>FP004340TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

>FP00598AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

>FP005521GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

Comment: +1.   With perl re, you can also do it without capture, using a positive lookbehind - e.g. `perl -pe 's/(?<=.)>/\n\n>/g'`, or `perl -pe 's/.\K>/\n\n>/g'`.    See `man perlre` and search for `Lookaround Assertions`

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` script would look for any line with an `>` in it, but add a newline at the beginning of that line (that's what `^` means in regex).

Probably try this:

```
sed 's/>/\n&/g' file
```

though whether `\n` produces a literal newline or not will depend on your `sed` version.  The desired behavior would be common on many Linux platforms but they are not all the same. (Perhaps clarify which distro and/or `sed` version, or try a more portable solution like Awk or Perl.)

```
awk -F '>' 'BEGIN { OFS="\n>" } { $1=$1 } 1' file
```

The `{ $1 = $1 }` hack forces Awk to split the line; it otherwise optimizes its processing by simply copying input to output if nothing changed on the line, but this causes it to think something actually changed.

If you need more than one newline, obviously put more than one; change `\n` to `\n\n` to get an empty line before each new line.

Comment: Apart from embedded systems, any full-fledged Lilnux distribution should have GNU sed AFAIK. Are you aware of any Linux flavors that do not?

Comment: Some let the admin pick a different `sed` version but yeah, I was mainly thinking of e.g. Busybox et al.

Comment: There is a correct and portable way to insert a newline in the replacement string and that's escaping an actual line break with a backslash: "*A line can be split by substituting a <newline> into it. The application shall escape the <newline> in the replacement by preceding it by a <backslash>.*"

Comment: by the way, your sed solution will not add a blank line between each "paragraph", it just separates them into lines. It only adds a blank line to the beginning, and only if the `>` was the first character. Same for the `awk` solution.

Comment: The last paragraph specifically addresses that. The OP's formatting was unclear and I felt it was easier to explain with a single newline with a footnote about adding more, rather than vice versa.

Comment: @Philippos True, but some beginners get thrown off by that syntax and imagine it must be wrong.

Comment: @terdon We cannot know whether this is for an embedded linux without GNU `sed`, but the `busybox` version of `sed` did also implement `\n` in the replacement to stay compatible with all that GNUish scripts.

Comment: Fair point about the formatting, @tripleee. I guess I felt it was clear since the OP explicitly asked for a blank line between each paragraph: "*I need to separated each paragraph with a blank line.*". You're still adding an extra empty line at the beginning though.

Answer (score 0):

**GNU sed**

```
$ sed 's/>/\n\n&/2g' input_file
```

---

**POSIXly sed**

```bsh
sed -e '
  y/>/\n/
  s/\n/>/
  s//&&>/g
' input_file
```

---

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!^)(?=>)/\n\n/g' input_file
```

```bsh
awk -v RS=">" -v ORS= '
NR>1&&sub(/^/,(!k++ ? ORS : "\n\n") RS)
' input_file
```

---